# Bootstrap paginated table sending only 10 row's data to server

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap table plugin. I'm populating a few columns' data dynamically and in left out columns the user will enter the data and submit the form containing this table. Before submitting the table, I'm iterating over each row of table using jQuery and sending this data to the server. But at server side I can see only 10 rows of data even though I have 70-80 lines. 
Can somebody point out what am I missing here?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#submit').on("click", function(event){
              $.post( 
                 "ReadTableData",
                 { tableData: getTableData() },
                 function(data,status) {
                   window.location.href = "ReadAjaxResponse?response="+data;
                 }

              );
          });
       });

        function getTableData() {
            var rows = $('table>tbody>tr');
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var cells = rows.eq(i).children('td');
                var operation = cells.eq(0).find('select').val();
                var select = cells.eq(1).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
                arr.push(operation + '|_|'+select);
            }
            return arr.join('@@');
    }
```

Comment: How are you paginating the table?

Comment: @Naveen Can you explain why you made the edit to add a single blank space to the start of the question? And now a second edit to add some unneeded highlighting?

Comment: @DavidG i was following this approach https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Comment: So your table only ever has 10 rows in it which means this approach cannot work.

Comment: @DavidG but this table has an option to show the entries ( 10, 25, 50,100) or we can configure it , but point is even though i am having so much data, only 10 rows are going

Comment: You are looping through the table which only ever has 10 rows in it (or 25/50/100), the other rows are stored somewhere else and inserted/removed by jQuery.

Comment: @DavidG is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got it . Hope this help someone :-

```
 function getTableData() {
             //// fnGetNodes function will iterate through whole table ..
                 var rows = $("#dbResultsTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes(); 
                 var arr = [];
                for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var cells = rows[i].cells;
                    var operation = cells[0].children[0].value;
                    var select = cells[1].children[0].value;
                if(cells[1].children[0].checked){
                    select=cells[1].children[0].value;
                }else{
                    select ='off';
                }
                   arr.push(operation + '|_|'+select);
                }
                return arr.join('@@');
        }
```

Note :- if you have dropdownMultiSelect Column in table so this code will get you list of all selected options in dropdown:-
Let's say in table column 11 is your dropDownMultiSelectBox then code will be :-

```
  var value = '';
    for(var x=0; x < cells[10].children[0].options.length;x++){
            if(cells[10].children[0].options[x].selected){
                value =value +cells[10].children[0].options[x].value + " , ";
            }               
        }
```